# How to Pass Relationship Parameters in Create Controller

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

I know this is probably extremely simple and I am just thinking about it too much, but I have two models: User and Entry.  I want to create an Entry that belongs to user and user has one entry.  I get the syntax as in `User::find(1)->entry->title`.  What I want is to pass a parameter through the controller using the url.

Entry Controller:

```
class EntryController extends \BaseController {

public function index($id)
{
    $user = User::find($id);
    $user->entries();

    return View::make('entries.index');
}

public function create($id)
{
    return View::make('entries.create');
}

public function store($id)
{   
    $user = user::find($id);
    $entry = new Entry;

    $entry->title = Input::get('title');
    $entry->content = Input::get('content');
    $entry->user()->associate($user);
    $entry->save();

    return redirect::to('users.show');
}
```

And here are my routes:

```
Route::get('/user/{id}/entry/create', ['as' => 'entries.create', 'uses' => 'EntryController@create']);

//entries put,post,delete

Route::post('/user/{id}/entry', ['as' => 'entries.store', 'uses' => ' EntryController@store']);`
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: Its in the title and the body.  How do I pass the user $id to the user from the entry controller?  This example does not work.  It is telling me that the user-object does not exist.

Comment: It seems that you have the id passed in the url, so it's accessible in those methods, but you didn't paste the real urls you got there. Show the form, maybe there is the problem.